# Add vertices to existing hook

Tags: animation, modifiers, vertices

I made an object and animated it with a hook. Afterwards, I added some vertices to the object that are therefore not attached to the hook. Is there a way to add those vertices to the already existing hook so they will follow its path through the animation? I am using Blender 2.79 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind, that if your hook object is animated, you need to place it in rest/initial position before attaching new vertices (for example switch to frame, where hook is located originaly). Otherwise they could behave incorrectly.

Once did it, enter *Edit mode* (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) and *Hook modifier* will provide additional options. **Select** button will show vertices that are already used for hooking. With those selected you should just select new vertices and click **Assign**. Done.

Comment: Thank you, that was so much easier than I thought! Yet still I could not find it in the Blender documentation.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that - I've always had to remove the hook and re-create it. That's really good to know.